# SSAS Label for a Measure is Different in Pivot Table than Source Project

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssas, pivot-table

I'm reviewing a SSAS database designed by someone else who is long gone. The SSAS project was designed in BIDS 2010 and has an Excel pivot table as the front-end to do the reporting.

When I look at a particular measure in the Excel pivot table it has a label "Actual 2014". However, when I look at the design in BIDS (looked in the cube design, data source view, and a few other areas) the label name is "Actual".

Where can I find where I can change the label being displayed in the Excel Pivot table?

EDIT

Here's a picture of what it looks like. You can see where it says "2014 Actual" and "2015 Budget". In the field list, but the underlying database all labels say "Actual" and "Budget" respectively (as it shows even in the "values" section).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be an Excel issue, not an SSAS.
In the Excel Pivot, Display the field list, and on the left, under Values, check the Value Field settings (right click to display).
The custom Name is probably different. 
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, I neglected to say that the label that shows "Actual 2014" is from the "Pivot Table Field List" itself - not from the result set that is on the worksheet. I added a picture to my original post to explain.

Comment: Then it is an SSAS question... try to look at the "calculations" tab under the "cube" setup in SSAS.

Comment: @ptownbro did you check the screen HilaDG showed? If you rename a measure in a PivotTable by typing over its name in the sheet or via that dialog it also renames it in the field list. So my guess is that Hila answered your question correctly. Can you double check?

Comment: Thanks Greg, Your answer was actually the right one.  Changing it Field Setting dialog didn't work for me. However, changing it directly on the sheet in the Pivot Table, also changed it in the field list. Thank you!